# TFS 2012 team build, How to specify package location

Tags: msbuild

when specified these parameters in the msbuild commandline args in the build definition,

/p:Configuration=Release /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 /P:UsePublishProfile=True /p:PublishProfile=CI /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation=..\Deployment\Files\Package\SubcontractGenerator.zip

it seems like msbuild ignore all of the parameters except /p:DeployOnBuild=true, so it just create the package in the droplocation_publishedWebsites\blah blah blah.

my question is how to get the build process to just create the package? because the CI publish profile specified there just to create the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to install Visual Studio 2012 on your build server for execute Ms Build with these arguments